# How to Google Linechars show Year/month/day/hours/minutes/seconds in php?

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

Hello i need to make a graph from database format is kinda simple: Time,Amount
My question how i can make google graph to show X axis by Year/month/day/hour/minutes.

My current code:

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

```
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Time', 'Amount'],
      <?php 
      for($i = 1; $i <= $Total; $i++){


        if($i == $Total){
        echo"[".date('Y/m/d/H/i', $Date[$i]).", ".$Amount[$i]."]";      
        }else{
        echo"[".date('Y/m/d/H/i', $Date[$i]).", ".$Amount[$i]."],";      
        }
      }
      ?>

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
```

I dont know how to formulate my question right but here is a picture how i imagine it should look like:
[image: Ignore another lines. It should be only one line]

Ignore another lines. It should be only one line